# Tool for visualizing story trees

Tags: windows, data-visualization, graphs, text

I'm looking for a tool that allows one to visualize story trees. Such trees have been depicted in a number of articles within the area of information science applied to media studies. A fitting example is the [article](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3132847.3132852?casa_token=HgnCzZhmet0AAAAA:2XyqjQvnYItcVuo7msaUZxDINoCNt6dxfbmh6bm1ZKqGM9MlpmQkPDgLoLboCei5S4eGegieON8) "Growing Story Forest Online from Massive Breaking News" (2017) by B. Liu et al.

In this article, the following story tree is presented on p. 779:

[image]

The story tree in question visualizes and describes certain events leading up to the American Presidential Elections in 2016. I'm currently doing research on algorithms that might in the future be used to help conducting parliamentary inquiries in the Netherlands.
I'd like to be able to create similar trees with an intuitive software application.

**Question**: do any tools or software programs exist that allow one to create such story trees (and perhaps also story graphs)?

The software would preferably work on Windows 11. Ideally, it would be free, but if no free options are available I would be willing to spend about 50 Euros on it (in one go or in total for a subscription, e.g. five months when costs 10 Euros per month).